# Can't access folders mounted by sshfs after sleep (or when connection lost)

Tags: linux, mount, arch-linux, sshfs

Often, when I mount a filesystem via ssh:

```
sshfs user@remote: ~/Mounts/Remote
```

and the machine hibernates (closing the Laptop lid) if I wake up the machine I can't access the mounted folder. Furthermore, if I try to `ls` in the parent folder, the terminal freeze. The same also happens when the connection is somehow lost.

If try to unmount using

```
fusermount -u ~/Mounts/Remote
```

I can't do this because:

> fusermount: failed to unmount /home/yotama9/Mounts/Remote: Device or resource busy

I tried to kill ssh but I can't mount the folder again. `ls` in the folder still freezes.

How can I avoid this and fix this (Arch Linux)?

Comment: `killall -KILL sshfs`, and next time, mount with mount options from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/6709/sshfs-mount-that-survives-disconnect/#639735).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suffer the same problem in Ubuntu Linux.
What I do after resume:

```
$ killall -9 sshfs
```

Then, umount

```
$ fusermount -u ~/far_projects
```

and mount again the remote filesystem.

```
$ sshfs -o idmap=user youruser@server:/projects ~/far_projects
```

Comment: Thanks. I replaced ``killall`` with ``killall -9``

Comment: I suggest making a script for more than one or two shares. It makes life a lot easier.

Comment: Works on macOS too.

Answer (score 8):

As noted [here](https://serverfault.com/a/639735/261445), this is your solution:

```
 -o reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3
```

As an example usage: https://github.com/aktos-io/dcs-tools, take a look at `make mount-root` target.

Comment: More details here https://serverfault.com/questions/6709/sshfs-mount-that-survives-disconnect/#639735

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue on my laptop.

All you need is to include the lazy unmount option (z) in your unmount command:

```
$ fusermount -uz ~/Mounts/Remote
```

Then just remount the same way you normally would.

Also, it's worth noting that I use the reconnect option (-o reconnect) which will maintain the connection through any hiccups (like closing your lid and coming back a few minutes later).

You can also look into a solution like [afuse](http://afuse.sourceforge.net/) which is an auto-mounter for fuse filesystems (sshfs included) to save you the hassle of unmounting/remounting every time.

One final auto-mount option is using [autofs with sshfs](http://www.tjansson.dk/?p=84).